# Make shortcuts appear in multiple menus

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am using a `TextBox` in a custom `UserControl` that I am creating. It seems that the default contextmenu doesn't show the shortcuts for Cut, Copy, Paste. This is fine, as long as they are just working.

But my `Form` using the `UserControl` has a `MenuStrip` that contains these default shortcuts as well. But the Cut, Copy, Paste commands are not working anymore, now that the shortcuts are assigned to the `MenuStrip`.

How can I use shortcuts at multiple positions in my forms? What is the best way to pass a global command like Cut and post it deeper into my `UserControl`? And is it possible to add the shortcuts to the default contextmenu of the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MenuStrip item or ToolStrip item doesn't change the focus when it is clicked or its shortcut keystroke is pressed.  Which is the ticket to implementing this functionality, the form's ActiveControl tells you which control has the focus.  You just need to check if it is a TextBox.  Like this:

```
    private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var box = this.ActiveControl as TextBoxBase;
        if (box != null) box.Copy();
    }
```

Do the same for the Paste() and Cut() methods.  You can further enhance the UI by selectively enabling these menu/toolbar items by subscribing to the Application.Idle event and checking if the ActiveControl is a text box and the text box or clipboard contains any text.  Like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) {
        Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
    }

    void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var box = this.ActiveControl as TextBoxBase;
        copyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = box != null && box.Text.Length > 0;
        cutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = copyToolStripMenuItem.Enabled;
        pasteToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = box != null && Clipboard.ContainsText();
    }
```

Comment: Ok sure, I could pass these methods to the box. Thanks. But who is the one receiving the events first? Is this a bubble up kind of way? So the focused items gets the control first and passes it to the form later on? Why doesn't the default Ctrl+X work in the TextBox anymore? I would believe that we are dealing with a bubble down.

Comment: No, the shortcut keystrokes you assigned make the menu/toolstrip item get the Click event first.  The active control won't see it.  No bubbling.  With the code I posted, Ctrl+X will now explicitly call the text box' Cut() method.  Making it work like it always did.

Comment: I find it strange that an explicit call is needed to keep the commands like they are.

Comment: Well, don't reassign the Ctrl+X shortcut and you won't have to.

Comment: How would you make an `Edit` field in your main menu without reassigning the shortcut of CTRL+X to the menu strip? That doesn't sound as an option either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just enabled the property of textbox for the same and it will start responding.

Just verify that [myTextBox.ShortcutsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx) = TRUE;

Comment: ShortcutsEnabled is already set to true. *Select All* is working properly, but Cut Copy and Paste are not. They are taken over by the main menu I think. But also for *Select All*, there is no shortcut in the menuItem saying: `CTRL+A`